# Best option to POST on facebook timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

I need to make POSTs to facebook page timeline (not auto posts, but when a user on an enterprise application submits a form). Note that a user should bot be logged in on facebook!

I've searched a lot and seems i should use graph api to do this... but, it's possible to achieve this without creating a facebook app?

I don't wish any user have this app... i just need to make POSTs to a facebook page that i own. So, it's not a public app.

I've made some tests with graph api explorer, after creating an app, and i'm trying to POST and always get error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.".

So, i'm using the correct access token (app access token in this case)... how can i test this? I should have my app submitted to be reviewed already? I just want to make some tests, to see if this actually works as i need to... don't wish to publish app now.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An App Token is the wrong Token to post to a Page. You would need to use a **Page Token** for that. At least if you want to post "as Page". If you want to post "as User", you have to use a User Token. Everything you need to know is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#Creating

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Hi @luschn , thanks for your reply. Yes, sorry, i was referring to page token. So, when using page tokens, and after getting the page access token, facebook login will not be required, as when working with user tokens, am i correct? So, if i make a post to some pageid timeline, with the correct post parameters, including page token, i don't need to have any facebook user logged in / no facebook session... it is correct? Also, it's possible to test the entire workflow on some test page, even before the facebook app is being revised or even before i submit it to review? Thanks!

Comment: user and page tokens are only valid for 2 hours by default, so if you want to store it, you should use an extended page token that is valid forever. take a look at the links i posted to find out how to create those.

Comment: you can test everything without review, permissions work without review for everyone with a role in the app. you should create a hidden page just for testing though.